# Does std::thread make any guarantee about what's happened when its constructor returns?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

If you call one of the nonempty `std::thread` constructors, is there any guarantee about the state of the thread when the constructor returns (assume the thread start-routine has a long lifespan)? Do you know whether the thread has actually started (i.e. its start-routine has been entered)?

Comment: The comment by @RbMm is rather snarky (or perhaps it can be misunderstood that way) but the big and unavoidable truth behind it is: if you need to know that then you're writing your C++ program with threads wrong.  You need to grok that fully w.r.t. concurrency semantics and then you'll understand how to write C++ with std::thread correctly.  You really have to know how much - or actually, _how little!_ - you can depend on when you write a program with concurrency.

Comment: @davidbak - I've worked with pthreads, and understand that it makes no guarantee of startRoutine entry. That's straightforward and generic. There are circumstances when you would want to know - and, this is implemented easily on an application-specific basis. Perfectly reasonable - and more flexible - that it is not guaranteed by pthreads itself. I was just curious about `std::thread`'s behavior because it's probably/effectively a pthread wrapper; my question was just academic curiosity.

Comment: @davidbak - I was 99.9% sure there was no guarantee - after all, you'd need a "hook" in between the startRoutine and `std::thread` constructor, which isn't the case...but I was curious nonetheless. Instinct was right - in this case - but it's sometimes nice just to have another human's confirm, especially when you're working with something new. :)

Comment: @StoneThrow - that's ok - my comment was actually based on the fruits of _bitter experience_ ...  And I agree there are circumstances where you want to know ... and in that case you've got to use standard concurrency mechanisms (e.g., fences) to find out because what you're _guaranteed_ is minimal (other languages too besides C++) - frankly, I find it is best to consider all of the C++ standard library mechanisms for concurrency to be low-level things to build on - or, preferably, that _someone else_ has built on! and tested! - to give you higher-level easier-to-use-correctly constructs.

Comment: can not be such guarantee, and more important knowledge about *its start-routine has been entered* nothing give you at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread):

> The completion of the invocation of the constructor *synchronizes-with* (as defined in [`std::memory_order`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)) the beginning of the invocation of the copy of `f` on the new thread of execution.

So the constructor will finish before the supplied function starts, but otherwise there are no guarantees.

In particular, you do not know what will happen between the end of the constructor and the start of the command following the constructor. The supplied function might – or might not – appear to have started at the same time that the constructor finishes.

At the other end of the spectrum, the supplied function might start after your main thread finishes (barring some other consideration, such as `join`ing the `std::thread`).

Comment: I'm not sure if the quoted fragment guarantees that the constructor will always finish before the new thread starts. `std::memory_order` seems to deal with atomics and the memory model.    If there are no atomics involved, there's no need for any synchronization between the caller and the thread.

Comment: @zkoza - [*https://preshing.com/20130823/the-synchronizes-with-relation/*](https://preshing.com/20130823/the-synchronizes-with-relation/) - this mean that all *user code* inside constructor (and any code before constructor) is finished and and have visible size effect before *user code* in new thread begin executed

Comment: @zkoza It does not matter what `std::memory_order` deals with. It is only the terminology that is referenced, not the subject. The important aspect is describing the order in which things occur; it does not matter what those things are. A better argument would be that `std::memory_order` uses "synchronizes-with" instead of defining it. (I thought about omitting that link from the quote, but the result made it look like I was dishonestly hiding something.)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the description at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread :

> Threads begin execution immediately upon construction of the
> associated thread object (**pending any OS scheduling delays**), starting
> at the top-level function provided as a constructor argument. :

This tells you that while it is safe to assume that the new thread will start its execution quickly, that is, most likely within microseconds,   you do not know what the operating system delay will be. If you're  on a single-core single-thread machine, all your threads AND the operating system will share the same hardware resources, and all will be executed in turn in their time windows. You should make no assumptions as to who will take the first window and how long will it last.

In other words, you can safely assume that creating an `std::thread` object is nothing but informing the operating system that you kindly ask it to create a new thread with a given function as the starting point, but you do not know when exactly the OS will kindly do so.

So the answer is: no, you can assume nothing about whether the other thread is already running or not. Sometimes it is, sometimes it is not.